# Unable to create spark pods in OCP with read write permission

Tags: apache-spark-2.0

I have unique issue.

My setup

OCP Cluster : OCP version 4.10
Weka Storage :

We used this solution to deploy spark pods.

We mount Weka storage and mount the weka storage volume in pods using values.yaml file

We deploy spark pods with helm

values.yaml file

---

worker:
extraVolumes:
- name: pvc-1ad02131-9edb-4fb4-a328-7a4a5f618ade
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: test-spark1
extraVolumeMounts:
- name: pvc-1ad02131-9edb-4fb4-a328-7a4a5f618ade
mountPath: '/spark1'

#helm install spark-cluster-spark1 oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/spark --values values.yaml

[root@lab-worker-3 hitachi]# oc get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS              RESTARTS        AGE
spark-cluster-spark1-master-0      1/1     Running             0               3d3h
spark-cluster-spark1-worker-0      1/1     Running             0               3d3h
spark-cluster-spark1-worker-1      1/1     Running             0               3d3h

[root@lab-worker-3 hitachi]#  oc rsh spark-cluster-demo1-worker-0

$ df -Th
Filesystem            Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay               overlay  270G  159G  112G  59% /
tmpfs                 tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                 tmpfs    252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm                   tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 tmpfs    252G   93M  252G   1% /etc/passwd
SPARK1                wekafs   4.6T   64K  4.6T   1% /spark1
/dev/mapper/rhel-root xfs      270G  159G  112G  59% /etc/hosts
tmpfs                 tmpfs    503G   20K  503G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                 tmpfs    252G     0  252G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                 tmpfs    252G     0  252G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                 tmpfs    252G     0  252G   0% /sys/firmware
$ cd /spark1
$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
$ exit

Why we are unable to mount as read write in spark pods